# using sed command subtitution

Tags: linux, sed

How to only specific value substitute in sed command

for example,

```
Linux system
Windows syste
Mac    syste
```

I tried this command

> sed 's/syste/system/g' file.txt

```
safwanpaloli@hello:~/linx$ sed 's/syste/system/g' new.txt 
Linux systemm
Windows system
Mac   system
```

I expected result

```
Linux system
Windows system
Mac   system
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `sed 's/system/syste/g;s/syste/system/g' new.txt`.

Comment: Okay, this is the craziest solution so far.

Comment: Well, this is definitely POSIX compliant and I don't need to think whether `\b` or `\?` is supported in non-GNU sed.

Comment: The simplest solution would probably be: `sed -e 's/syste$/system/' file`

Comment: I agree, for the OP's input where `syste` always appear at the end of lines.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute the `m` too, but only if it's there.

```
sed 's/system\?/system/g'
```